# Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.scroll_behavior

Tags: android, android-design-library

Here is my activity in which I have used coordinate layout and view pager.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include layout="@layout/venue_app_bar_content" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white50" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

When run app, it get crashed with message : 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.scroll_behavior

Comment: The above code is in android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: It seems like you've set your own (incorrect) value for the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` Resource String. The value in the support library is `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior`. Look in your `res/values*/` folders, most likely in a `strings.xml` file, to see if you have a value there. If so, delete it.

Comment: Right, that's what you get when `CoordinatorLayout` can't create an instance of a class specified in `layout_behavior`. Somewhere it's trying to create an instance of `android.support.design.widget.scroll_behavior`, so figure out wherever it's getting that incorrect class name from. The rest of your stack trace would help you find out where, if it's not coming from what you posted.

Comment: Oh sorry! I have declared a string variable with same key. Thanks @MikeM.

Answer (score 17):

The layout_behavior line must be replace with this:

```
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

make sure this dependency exists in build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was using `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"` and replaced it with recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

What you should try is to delete the string resource in strings.xml file.Thats what solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have androidx then you should manually do the mapping of classes used in XML to the new ones:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate